# Flask app: how to handle multiple requests that should be responded in no time

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, multithreading, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My Flask application is built around some third-party API, I have hundreds of thousands  requests.
The problem is their API requires responses to be sent very fast whereas I need to do many things: check the request parameters, verify the webhook request, search for a user in our database, etc. which takes time. Even if it looks pretty fast, it usually causes the timeout error for that API.

So, to overcome this requirement, I create a new thread to handle the request and sent the immediate response:

```
@public_route('/some/api')
class User_request(Resource):
    def post(self):
        request_headers = request.headers
        data = request_payload()
        event = data.get('event')
        content = get_field_value(data, 'data.content')
        handle_request(data, event, content)
        return jsonify('ok')

###
def handle_request(data, event, content):
 app = current_app._get_current_object()
    thr = Thread(target = _handle_request_in_thread, 
                args=[app, data, event, content])
    thr.start()

def _handle_request_in_thread(app, data, event, content):
    # Here is where I actually handle the request
    pass
```

As a result, I don't have the timeout error from that API anymore but I often have the error on my side: "RuntimeError: can't start new thread". I was thinking of using a queue in some way but I'm not sure if I have to create a new thread on every new task in the queue and whether I should use the Python Queue or some library like RQ.

Comment: flask can use `Celery` to run tasks in separated threads: [Background Tasks with Celery — Flask Documentation (2.3.x)](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/patterns/celery/)

Comment: @furas Unfortunately, this option is not available as I'm developing using Windows (even though the production is on Linux). I implemented this with Redis.

Comment: It seems to me that  requests are coming in faster than they can be processed and that is why the number of active threads you have continues to grow until you can no longer create a new thread. Even if you use an external queue to enqueue requests they will be enqueued faster than they can be dequeued and processed if you have a finite number of worker threads to do this processing. Thus, the queue will continue to increase in size indefinitely unless there is some sufficient lull in the request rate to allow the queue to empty.

Comment: @Booboo probably you are right, but how can it be solved?

Comment: If a requests takes .1 seconds to to process and they come in at the rate of 100 per second (i.e. 10 per .1 seconds), then you need 10 active threads that are able to run concurrently to keep up with the requests. This assumes *perfect* concurrency, i.e. each thread always has a CPU core available to run on when it needs to and there is no contention among the threads (e.g. serializing on the Global Interpreter Lock).  For 10 threads to suffice you would also need 10 cores. (more...)

Comment: But since such an idealized situation does not exist, it will in reality take more than .1 seconds to process each requests and therefore the actual number of worker threads required will be somewhat higher. At least this is my analysis. So how long does it take to process a request and what is the arrival rate and how CPU-intensive is the processing and how many cores do you have? These are questions that you need to answer for yourself. Consider this: if the processing were 100% CPU intensive, because of the GIL N threads would be no better than a single thread and there is no solution.